# Using fieldset: Invalid field core for SObject Case Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, fieldsets

Extension:

```
public class fieldset1display() {

    public string fieldset1 { get; set; }

    public fieldset1display(ApexPages.StandardController std) {
        fieldset1 = 'fieldset1';
        this.cs = (Case) std.getRecord();
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="fieldset1display" >
...
<apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Case.FieldSets[fieldset1]}" var="f" >
        <tr>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!f.label}"  /></td>

            <!-- Below line causes error: Invalid field core for SObject Case -->
            <td><apex:outputField value="{!Case[f]}" /></td> 
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
...
```

1. It works if I directly reference to the fieldset by `value="{!$ObjectType.Case.FieldSets.fieldset1}"` in the repeat tag.
2. It works if I use the `ouptputText` tag in the error line (returns id for lookup and true/false for checkbox)

But, I'm curious to know why it's throwing this error when I use the outputField. I'm trying to do this because I can pass any fieldset name dynamically based on a certain field in the case.

Comment: Another mention of "core" [Dynamic binding: Error: Invalid field core for SObject Case](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000985xIAA) that suggests this is a platform bug.

Comment: Thanks @KeithC for sharing. Apart from direct reference in vfp, just to display a fieldset, is there any other way to pass the fieldset name from extension?

Comment: Not something I'm very familiar with. but `{!$ObjectType.Case.FieldSets[fieldset1]}` looks appropriate to me.